# Block Lower Triangular (BLT) in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I am going to have the final "BLT" of a simulation in the OpenModelica environment. I saw there is a flag for the compiler (I mean "bltdump "), but when I insert it in Simulation\General\C/C++ Compiler Flags (Optional) field, it does not work. could you please advise me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable it under Simulation/Translation flags/Additional Translation Flags: `-d=bltdump`

Comment: when we use other flags"bltmatrixdump ", we see  3 BLT files, what are they? i mean why three? –

Comment: From what I can tell, that might happen if you have independent parts of the simulation. You could run the equations in each file in parallel.

Comment: I have a question about the BLT formed in the HTML file. how can we see the equations displayed in rows with abbreviations Eq_1,...?